# Gate driver IR2110 doesn't work - Full bridge

Tags: gate-driving, full-bridge

I am using two gate drivers (IR2110), each driving a phase leg of the full bridge. Everything has been wired up according to the datasheet http://www.infineon.com/dgdl/ir2110.pdf?fileId=5546d462533600a4015355c80333167e

Values of capacitors are 1 microFarad and fast-recovery diodes are used. Load is a resistor (tried values between 100 ohm - 2 kohm) but the problem is that neither VGS of upper MOSFET's of each phase leg can be seen as well as no output voltage across the load resistor can be seen.

The input signals LIN and HIN are complementary signals from MCU and work perfectly fine.

What can be the reason? Cboot not able to charge and/or discharge?

**Also, is it necessary that if I set Vcc = 12V that the drain supply of upper MOSFET's needs to be within range 12V - 500V ?**

[image: http://lh5.ggpht.com/-9vD29K-Hc6c/UWOhOVmkSSI/AAAAAAAAQaA/x7pdREpPUgg/image_thumb%25255B6%25255D.png?imgmax=800]

Comment: Anyone able to help with your question already knows what an H-bridge is. A schematic of *your actual circuit with your MOSFETs and other parts labeled* is far more likely to get a helpful response than a generic circuit with IGBTs from a textbook...

Comment: I don't see any `LIN` or `HIN` in the schematic you've posted.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to check:  When The low side is turned on, the high side cap (between Vb and Vs) is charged to VCC.  This cap provides voltage for the high side gate.  So when you turn the low side on, the cap should have VCC on it.  When you turn off the low side and turn on the high side, the cap's high side floats up, so you need enough voltage to drive the gate and enough capacitance to hold it up there until you switch down and re-charge the cap.  You must also provide enough time switched "low" to charge it back up.  So Vcc needs to be about 15 volts or so, enough to turn on the FET but not enough to exceed VGS.  The low side of the cap floats on top of the high-side's source, so it may be 500 volts from ground but VGS is still only 15.  If you don't switch to ground often enough or use too small a value, the cap will lose its charge and the thing won't work.  I think 20 - 50 uf is about right unless you are switching fast.